# What is the simplest proof that the mutual information $I(X:Y)$ is always non-negative?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

What is the simplest proof that mutual information is always non-negative? i.e., $I(X;Y)\ge0$

Comment: Convexity of the function $t\mapsto t\log t$.

Comment: In addition, the convexity properties require the coefficients in the linear combination sum 1. Then, as p(x,y) is a probability distribution, it fullfits such condition.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By definition,
$$I(X;Y) = -\sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y} p(x,y) \log\left(\frac{p(x)p(y)}{p(x,y)}\right)$$
Now, negative logarithm is convex and $\sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y} p(x,y) = 1$, therefore, by applying Jensen Inequality we will get,
$$I(X;Y) \geq -\log\left( \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y} p(x,y) \frac{p(x)p(y)}{p(x,y)} \right) = -\log\left( \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y} p(x)p(y)\right) = 0$$
Q.E.D

Comment: What if the variables are continuous?

Comment: @becko The same arguments hold, you just have to replace the summations by integrals.

Comment: why must be the sum of p(x,y) = 1?

Comment: @Peter p(x,y) is a probability distribution, and so the sum of p(x,y) = 1

Comment: But how does $\sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y} p(x,y) = 1$ imply that $\sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y} p(x)p(y) = 1$?

Comment: @JacKeown It is not implication. $\sum_{x \in X}\sum_{y \in Y}p(x)p(y) = \left(\sum_{x \in X}p(x)\right)\left(\sum_{y \in Y}p(y)\right)$

Comment: @TenaliRaman Yes. I overlooked that you could take the $p(x)$ out of the inner sum. You can only do this because $p(x)$ is the same for every value of $y$.

Comment: If $X=Y$ (deterministically), then isn't $I(X;Y)$ equal to the entropy of $Y$? And if $Y$ is a continuous r.v., can't its entropy be negative? For example, if $Y$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $(0, 0.5)$, then $p(x)=2$ on that interval, and the entropy is the integral of $-2 \log_2(2) = -2$ on that interval, which gives an entropy of $-1$.

Comment: @TenaliRaman Does Jensen's inequality apply for two variables? I mean the terms inside the log are function of $x, y$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to show this without using Jensen's inequality, but using the fact that $log(x) \leq x-1$ with equality iff $x = 1$

$I(X,Y) = \mathbb{E} \left(\log \left[\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x) f_Y(y)}\right]\right)=\mathbb{E} \left(-\log \left[\frac{f_X(x) f_Y(y)}{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}\right]\right)$

But $log(x) \leq x-1$ throughout it's domain, and therefore $-\log(x)\geq 1-x$. Then we have:
\begin{align*}
I(X,Y) &\geq \mathbb{E} \left(1-\left[\frac{f_X(x) f_Y(y)}{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}\right]\right) \\
&= 1- \mathbb{E} \left(\left[\frac{f_X(x) f_Y(y)}{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}\right]\right)\\
&= 1-\int_{x}\int_{y} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\left[\frac{f_X(x) f_Y(y)}{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}\right]dx dy\\
&=1- \left[\int_{x}f_X(x) dx\right] \left[\int_{y} f_Y(y) dy\right]  = 1-1\cdot 1 = 0
\end{align*}