# Can conditioning increase Entropy?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Is there any circumstance in which conditioning can increase entropy?

Can $H(X|Y) > H(X)$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy lists $H(X|Y)\le H(Y)$ among the "other properties"

Comment: Thank you, that helps!

Comment: Conditioning will never increase the entropy. See this for a proof: [Alternative proof that conditioning reduces entropy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704452/alternative-proof-that-conditioning-reduces-entropy/2704699). Or, since $I(X;Y)$ (mutual information) is equal to $H(X)-H(X\mid Y)$, you can use the fact that $I(X;Y)\ge 0$, a proof of which is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159501/mutual-information-always-non-negative/159544).

Comment: Thank you @MinusOne-Twelfth